# SGP4: the accumulation of error in radial, in-track and cross-track

Tags: collision-avoidance, risk-management, sgp4

I'm propagating the trajectories of 2 LEO satellites (altitude 700 km) in 7 days and calculating the radial, in-track and cross-track distances to determine the risk of collision.

JSPoC states that 0.5 km in the radial direction is enough for an alert. However, in 7 days SGP4 propagation the error accumulates.

How does error accumulate in this three directions per day? How to deal with error accumulation in risk assessment?

I would appreciate for the papers.

[image]

Comment: There are some interesting related links in the following questions and their answers, but they are not duplicates: [TLE/SGP4 state vector accuracy assessment](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30286/12102) as well as [What is the accuracy / uncertainty of Two Line Elements (TLEs)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6167/12102) and also [Is SGP4 propagation necessarily more accurate near the epoch chosen for TLE generation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29751/12102)

Comment: I think the answer to *How to deal with error accumulation in risk assessment?* is don't use SGP4 for anything critical like risk assessment.