# Conversion of osculating orbital elements to TLE mean elements

Tags: orbital-elements, sgp4

I am looking for a method to resample TLE data, so they are regularly sampled. I wanted to use physical propagation to calculate elements at given time. However, the propagation of TLE by SGP4 returns state vector, which can be transformed to osculating elements. Is it possible to transform osculating to TLE mean elements?
From what I understand, you need to specify propagation model for osculating to mean conversion. In our case, this model is SGP4. However, on what time scales should the averaging be done over?
And what you think about using zero time propagation with SGP4 model to guess the input mean element to match osculating elements? Will such approach even produce unambiguous solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is software available for writing two line element files from Keplerian elements?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33698)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [What is the current state of the art in converting between mean and osculating orbital elements?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65144)