# When is/will be the symposium to revisit the Karman line and consider the "McDowell line"?

Tags: law, international-politics, karman-line

In the **January 16, 2019** Sixty Symbols video [Where is the edge of space?](https://youtu.be/nILOHp79njQ) Dr Meghan Gray from the University of Nottingham discusses Jonathan McDowell's paper [The edge of space: Revisiting the Karman Line](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07894) and says:

> There’s been enough recent attention to the idea that the Karman line needs to be redefined, that the organizations that deal with aeronautical things and the organizations that deal with astronautical things **are proposing to get together in the coming year to have a symposium to look at the scientific and the political and whatever arguments go into this to see if we need to actually have a definition of where is space and what that (line) might be.**

**Question:** Has this symposium been named and scheduled? Has it taken place? What are the aeronautical and astronautical organizations that are sponsoring it?

[image: Karman line vs McDowell line from Sixty Symbols]

---

For further reading and background on the McDowell paper and spacecraft operating below 100 km, see:

- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32848/12102) to *Why is FAI considering lowering the Karman Line to 80 km?*
- [Did the Soviet Union put an unmanned satellite in “very low orbit”above the Kármán line which used aerodynamic attitude control?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31413/12102)
- [Have spacecraft ever dipped below the Karman line and then safely continued spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29704/12102)

**Please:** limit debate about the underlying physics or definitions. This question is about the symposium event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symposium will not be held.  Source: I asked Jonathan.

Comment: In this particular case this may have to serve as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did Jonathan tell you why not? Does the FAI want to remain in ignorance?