# Why would oxygen be stored as a super critical fluid?

Tags: fuel, oxygen, apollo-13, supercritical-fluids

[Organic Marble just answered a question about Apollo 13](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39231/25224) in terms of the storage of Oxygen, and posted some fascinating stuff, including the fact that Oxygen was **stored as a super-critical fluid**.

I was just wondering **what the benefits of storing Oxygen as a [super-critical fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) were** and why this was done for Apollo 13? As a follow-up question I was also wondering if this is **still the standard for storage of Oxygen**?

**Note:** I know very little of fluid-dynamics.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The same system was used on Shuttle - allow me to discuss that, the design philosophy applies to Apollo as well (Shuttle deleted the fans though, and had a special Avoid-Apollo-13-circuit in the O2 tanks).

> A supercritical fluid is any substance at a temperature and pressure
>   above its critical point, where distinct liquid and gas phases do not
>   exist.

(wikipedia link in question)

The lack of distinct phases is important for systems like the Apollo and Shuttle cryo systems.  The heat transfer properties of gaseous O2 and liquid O2 are quite different - if the fluid was allowed to have gas bubbles in it, hot spots could occur on the heater surfaces adjacent to bubbles, which could be disastrous in the pure O2 environment.

Keeping the O2 and H2 cryogens for the fuel cells at supercritical conditions is a smart design for several reasons.

- There is no concern about keeping the fluids at the tank outlet. The supercritical fluids occupy the entire tank volume.
- It's simple to manage the properties of the fluids - it can be done
  with a relatively straightforward heater / pressure sensor control system.
- No pumps or other devices are needed to expel the fluids, the high
  pressure in the tanks does that for you.
- No slosh dynamics because no liquid/vapor boundary (h/t to
  [Tristan](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/512/tristan) for the comment, also mentioned in the reference [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39231/6944))

Here are tank quantity / pressure / temperature graphs for the Shuttle tanks.

[image]

[image]

Downsides include having to use power to run the heaters, relatively heavy and expensive tanks - they have to withstand high pressures, and are vacuum-jacketed, and of course, the danger of running heaters in a pure O2 environment.

Shuttle had a special circuit in its O2 tanks to prevent an Apollo 13 type disaster.  Sensors measured the current going into and out of the heater panels. If the in- and out- currents weren't very similar, a short on the heaters was suspected, and the heaters were tripped off.

[image]

Source: Orbiter Systems Instructor Console Handbook (not online)

There's a nice description of the Orbiter cryo system in the [Press Manual](https://archive.org/details/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/page/n261). Here's an O2 tank system schematic from there.

[image]

Comment: Wow the tid-bit about the failsafe put into place after Apollo 13 was interesting, there's two because they're redundant right? If one heater fails or is shut off due to a malfunction, the other can continue to run?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Let me check the rules, they were pretty paranoid about it, may not have used the whole heater system.

Comment: If I want to know a bit more about how super-critical fluids remove the need for pumps should I ask that in a separate question? Is it simply because the turbidity of swapping states automatically distributes the fluid homogeneously?

Comment: Well, you've got a fluid in a tank at 850 psi, if you open a valve connected to that tank, it's gonna come squirting out!  Then the pressure starts to drop, and when it drops enough, the heaters come on and bring the pressure back up.  I'll add some words about supercritical fluids at the top of the answer.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn there were redundant A and B heaters in each tank as shown on the drawing. The flight rule A9-255 says if a heater trips off while it's powered (so presumably really a short) the redundant heater will be used only under certain special circumstances  too long to explain in a comment - but they really didn't want to use that tank at all if they didn't have to https://archive.org/details/flight_rules_generic/page/n1485

Comment: There's also the benefit of no slosh dynamics affecting CG or loads.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I don't think "not needing any pumps" is directly related to supercriticality in any way — it's just a useful side effect of keeping the tanks at high pressure, which keeping the contents above the critical pressure requires anyway. But supercriticality does mean that the entire tank is filled with a single homogeneous phase, rather than having liquid in some parts of the tank and gas in others, which simplifies some other things (e.g. no sloshing, no need for ullage motors to allow safely starting the engines in microgravity).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that was an eloquent way of explaining it to someone who has no prior knowledge of fluid dynamics. Thank you for the comment :)!

Comment: this answer about supercritical oxygen is a good read https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/122246/16035

Comment: @uhoh nice, and appears to address Uwe's diving-bottle concerns well. We used the Z form of the ideal gas law in the Shuttle Mission Simulator for high pressure helium tanks.

Comment: How do you deal with the curve in the graph as the fuel levels are depleted? It seems as if the rest of the system has to rapidly adjust the pressure and temparature as fuel is expended. Do you think that is a good follow up question?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn the heaters were set to keep the pressure up around 850 psi (O2), 220 psi (H2), way above the "vapor dome".

Comment: @OrganicMarble ahhh... I was misreading the graph, I got it now. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a chemist but I'll go out on a limb and suggest a way to resolve some issues in comments.

It looks to me as though as long as you are **above both** the *critical pressure* and *critical temperature* at the same time, it's a supercritical fluid; thus the name.

So as long as the pressure is above 50.4 bar and the temperature is above 154.5 K (-118.6 C) it's supercritical. And in a tank it's going to be either *all supercritical* or none, unless you have a transient gradient in temperature or pressure.

[This **excellent answer**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/122246/16035) explains that the supercritical phase of oxygen and many other gases can often behaive similarly to a "normal" ideal gas and not be "wonky with all sorts of amazing, bizarre properties." **I strongly recommend giving a read!**

---

[image]

**above:** https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/oxygen-d_1422.html

**below:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phase-diag2.svg

[image]

---

Here's a video of what a liquid + gas phase transitioning to a supercritical state looks like. The line where the surface of the liquid meets the gas just fades away and the color (this happens to be chlorine) becomes half way between the darker liquid and the lighter gas. Pretty cool, especially if you watch how it converts back to liquid + gas at the end!

Comment: That's a neat video. I assume what we're seeing at the end is transient [critical opalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_opalescence) as the gas and liquid phases become distinct and then gradually separate under gravity? I.e. basically the phases start out all mixed up as the fluid hits the critical point, and then the liquid phase gradually rains down while the gas bubbles up?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it could be, I don't know, but here's another interesting video; https://youtu.be/GEr3NxsPTOA

Comment: @uhoh Wow! You have the best videos, that was immensely cool. It helps to actually see what everyone was talking about with having "all parts of the tank in the same phase". It's weird to wrap your mind around.

Comment: But oxygen sold in steel bottles under a pressure of 200 bar at room temperature is gaseous, not supercritical. The ideal gas law is valid for oxygen between 1 and 200 bar.

Comment: That was indeed cool, I've never witnessed the transition visually.

Comment: @Uwe all I have are the sources shown and the conclusions they explain. What you've said contradicts them, "it's not supercritical at room temperature and 200 bar" do you have a supporting source for that? Let's get to the bottom of this the SE way, looking for the best supporting sources for facts cited. I'll be at the library tomorrow so I can do a proper literature search.

Comment: Scuba divers use the ideak gas law for air and oxygen bottles to calculate the amount of remaining gas for 200 down to 10 bar. This would not be possible if there is supercritical oxygen in the tank.

Comment: @Uwe I've just asked [Is oxygen above the critical point always supercritical fluid? Would it still appear to roughly follow the ideal gas law?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/122239/16035) Can you have a look and make sure you're comfortable with what I've written?

Comment: @Uwe You're talking about "liquid-like supercritical fluid", in your bottle it's gas-like, which is pretty much just a gas and it's being technically "supercritical" is usually ignored.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37049/18825   .. I am confused, no sloshing then what this anomally talks about?

Comment: @Prakhar "no sloshing" discussed on this page only applies to *supercritical oxygen*. Those two apollo spacecraft had liquid propellants, and some cryogenic liquid oxygen as well.

Comment: @uhoh So, only apollo 13 had such storage?

Comment: @Prakhar "no sloshing" only applies to gases and supercritical fluids (which are a lot like gases in this context). Liquid propellants are extremely common and they slosh like crazy! Spacecraft have all kinds of anti-slosh precautions. It's just that in the case of Apollo 11 (and a few others) those precautions may not have been good enough in some situations.

Comment: @Prakhar your link is referring to sloshing of *propellants* used in the Apollo *propulsion* system. This whole page is about *reactants* used in the Apollo and Shuttle *electrical* system.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to store as much oxygen in a given volume as possible, you have to increase the density significantly.  There's two ways to accomplish that.

- Low temperature (cyrogenic liquid)
- High pressure (supercritical fluid)

If you don't need to store it for very long (say during a launch), then cyrogenic liquid oxygen has lots of benefits.  You get maximum density and the tanks don't have to withstand high pressures.

But for an extended mission, cyrogenic storage is problematic.  You either need to have capacity to handle significant boiloff, or you need active cooling systems (which require power, mass, and complexity).  The alternative is to let it come up to ambient temperature and put up with the high pressures that requires.

So on a medium-to-long duration mission like Apollo, cryogenic storage costs a lot.  That makes the lower density of super critical fluids become an acceptable trade off.

Comment: But the supercritical fluid exists at high pressure AND low temperature. Look at the diagrams in the answer by Organic Marble. The critical point of oxygen is at 154.581 K, 5.043 MPa. The boiling point at  90.188 K is somewhat lower. The tanks for the Apollo fuel cells were designed for high pressure and thermal insulation for low temperature.

Comment: The Shuttle and Apollo tanks were both cryogenic and supercritical.  Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: The comment is right, but the answer still makes sense because cryogenic fluids require lower temperature and supercritical fluids require high pressure.

Comment: this answer about supercritical oxygen is a good read https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/122246/16035