# What happens when supercritical fuel tanks deplete below critical point?

Tags: tanks, supercritical-fluids

Gaseous fuel/oxidiser (eg H<sub>2</sub> / O<sub>2</sub>) is stored as a [supercritical fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) so it becomes homogenous; not prone to delivering matter with fluctuating densities, which would cause major stresses in rocket engines.

Sufficient temperature and pressure keeps the fuel supercritical.

What happens when sufficient contents of the tank has been expelled such that the contents drop below supercritical (where both liquid and gas are present)?

1. Do rockets not use the remaining contents?
2. Do they just use up the remaining contents without halting given the acceleration of the vehicle would make location of liquid and gaseous sections predictable?
3. Heat the contents so it stays supercritical until mostly empty ("wasting" the dreggs for safety's sake)?
4. Something else

Comment: Don’t they use header tanks to top off the pressure with gassed like Helium?

Comment: related: [Why would oxygen be stored as a super critical fluid?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39232/12102) and [Are there examples of a spacecraft designed for transitions from supercritical to liquid+gas mixtures?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39269/12102)

Comment: A  supercritical fluid  and [superfluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4) are very different kind of matter.

Comment: Propellants for rocket engines are not stored as supercritical fluids, as construction of the large tanks to contain the high pressures would be prohibitively heavy. The related question about supercritical fluids is talking about tanks used for purposes other than rocket engine propellants, such as electricity generation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the Shuttle, the flight rules cover these cases.

The O2 and H2 tanks had quantity "redlines" defined - operation of the tank heaters below those quantities could cause the heaters to overheat. The redlines were 2.5 % in the H2 tanks, 6.5 % in the O2 tanks.

> The 2.5 percent and 6.5 percent numbers are the minimum quantities
>   guaranteed to be obtainable prior to reaching maximum tank heater
>   temperature limits.

When (if) you got down to those quantities, you stopped using the tank.

Other sections of the rule covered the case of losing supercriticality.

> FOR SITUATIONS IN WHICH THE TANK PRESSURE GOES BELOW THE CRITICAL
>   PRESSURE BUT IS STILL ABOVE THE TWO-PHASE SATURATION PRESSURE, HEATERS
>   MAY BE USED (DUAL HEATERS ARE PREFERRED) TO RAISE THE PRESSURE BACK
>   ABOVE THE CRITICAL PRESSURE.
>
> IF THE TANK PRESSURE FALLS BELOW THE TWO-PHASE SATURATION PRESSURE,
>   THE HEATERS WILL BE DISABLED UNTIL NORMAL HEAT TRANSFER INTO THE TANK
>   RAISES THE PRESSURE ABOVE THE TWO- PHASE SATURATION PRESSURE. THE
>   HEATERS MAY BE OPERATED ONLY IN A CONTINGENCY SITUATION.

[Space Shuttle Flight Rules](https://archive.org/details/flight_rules_generic/page/n1491), Rule A9-258 and rationale

*Apologies for the all-caps but that is how the rules were written. The first quote is rule rationale and therefore not in all-caps.*

Here's a screen shot of an MCC cryo display about halfway through the STS-88 shuttle mission.

[image]

(Source: personal notes)

You can see that Tank(s) 5 have been depleted and are at their quantity redlines. Tank(s) 4 are in use and being depleted. Tank(s) 1 and 2 were used for ascent and early in the mission, Tank(s) 3 have hardly been used at all.

Note: Please keep in mind these supercritical fluids are *reactants* used in the Apollo and Shuttle *electrical power systems*.  They are not *propellants* used in the *propulsion systems*.

Comment: I've just asked [Are there examples of a spacecraft designed for transitions from supercritical to liquid+gas mixtures?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39269/12102)

Comment: They really didn't want anyone using those heaters without an alternative option.

Comment: Ah, the CDE window brings back so many memories...

Comment: re all-caps: [When did people decide that all caps means the writer is shouting?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/41249/33008) I ran across that by accident and then remembered this. I think there's another one here, with a NOTAM or weather report or some teletype-style output in an answer somewhere...