# What is the purpose of the aft skirt on the Space Shuttle and SLS Solid Rocket Boosters?

Tags: space-shuttle, sls, srb

The Solid Rocket Boosters (SRBs) used by the Space Shuttle and SLS have a skirt near the bottom.

**What is it for?** Is it only to support the stack?

[image: The SLS aft skirt]

Comment: To preserve their decency, obviously

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Main points about the SRB aft skirt are that they:

- bear the entire weight of the launch vehicle, prelaunch
- had (SLS SRB does not) four hold-down/support posts distributed the loads between the SRB and the mobile launcher platform (MLP); They contained nuts that detonated at SRB ignition.
- after launch, the Thrust Vector Control system (rock and tilt) inside the skirt aid the steering of the stack during first stage ascent
- contain Aft Booster Separation Motors (4) used in SRB separation

[image]

(SLS SRB (not STS) aft skirt)

> The cone- shaped aft skirt reacts the aft loads between the SRB and the mobile launcher platform. The **four aft separation motors are mounted on the skirt**. The aft section **contains avionics, a thrust vector control system** that consists of **two auxiliary power units** and **hydraulic pumps**, **hydraulic system**s and a **nozzle extension jettison system**.

https://space-shuttle.com/srb.htm

> The aft motors are located unsymmetrically which causes a small roll moment.
> The BSM's provide the needed side force to separate the boosters from the external tank at booster burnout.

Further:

https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2010/02/shuttle-boosters-sport-apu-fuel-pump-redesign-sts-134/

[image]

> Shuttle Boosters to sport APU fuel pump safety redesign from STS-134
>
> There are two self-contained, independent HPUs (Hydraulic Power Units) on each SRB. Each HPU consists of an Auxiliary Power Unit (APU), Fuel Supply Module (FSM), hydraulic pump, hydraulic reservoir and hydraulic fluid manifold assembly.
>
> The HPU components are mounted on the aft skirt between the rock and tilt actuators – which are part of the Thrust Vector Control system that drives the SRB nozzle to aid the steering of the stack during first stage ascent.
>
> The APUs and their fuel systems are isolated from each other, with each FSM (tank) containing 22 pounds of hydrazine.
>
> The fuel tank is pressurized with gaseous nitrogen at 400 psi, which provides the force to expel (positive expulsion) the fuel from the tank to the fuel distribution line, maintaining a positive fuel supply to the APU throughout its operation.
>
> The APU turbine assembly provides mechanical power to the APU gearbox, which drives the APU fuel pump, hydraulic pump and lube oil pump.
>
> The turbine exhaust of each APU flows over the exterior of the gas generator, cooling it, and is then directed overboard through an exhaust duct.

> AFT SKIRT CONFIGURATION
>
> The skirt is essentially
> a truncated conical shell reinforced by internal rings and stringers. Four
> **hold-down/support posts** which **distribute the prelaunch loads** to the mobile
> launch platform are **mounted integrally to the skirt**.
>
> The aft skirts of the SRB's provide the prelaunch support for the
> space Shuttle vehicle and are flight structured. They have been primarily
> designed for the flight loads (prelaunch) . The structure must also withstand
> the water impact loads. The SRB vehicle on re-entry impacts the water aft end
> first.

https://www.planetary.org/articles/20150310-sls-booster-engineer-interview

> As it was for the shuttle, the **aft SRB skirts will bear the entire weight of the launch vehicle**. Each skirt slides over four posts to hold the vehicle steady. To keep the shuttle steady while it ***twanged***, these posts used to contain explosive bolts (nuts) that fired when the vehicle pitched back to center—right at the moment of SRB ignition.

[image]

> Each SRB aft skirt houses a complex **thrust vector control** system (TVC), which **mechanically directs the nozzle** at the
> end of the booster to **steer the shuttle** during its initial ascent. The TVC consists of two hydraulic gimbal servo-actuators; each
> independently powered by its own auxiliary power unit (APU) and hydraulic system.

Aft BSM:

[image]

Hold Down post integration with aft skirt:

[image]

TVC:

[image]

[image]

Aft skirt detail:

[image]

[image]

links:

https://www.novamente.net/aerospace-problems/o.html

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42811024.pdf

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20030016601/downloads/20030016601.pdf

http://mirrors.josefsipek.net/www.capcomespace.net/dossiers/espace_US/shuttle/sts/solid_rocket_booster.htm

https://georgesrockets.com/GRP/Scale/ShuttleData/ICD_data.html

These link shave more info regarding TVC:

[Is it unusual to vector the thrust from an SRB?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14992/40489)

[How does a single SRB control attitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20755/40489)

Re: Twang:

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29919/40489

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53567/40489

Re: Modification of single SRB for use in the Ares I-X test flight in 2009:

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20090020529/downloads/20090020529.pdf

> Aft Skirt — The aft skirt, like the
> motor segments, uses existing Space Shuttle
> hardware. The Ground Systems team at KSC is
> removing the  thermal protection system ... so that additional
> ballast, booster deceleration motors (BDMs),
> and booster tumble motors (BTMs) can be installed.
>
> The aft skirt for Ares I-X, when operational, will include eight BDMs and four BTMs.

[image]

The aft skirt, while Shuttle-legacy
hardware, will have hardware added to meet the
requirements of Ares I-X.

Regards mention of ballast for Ares I-X only (Note, not SLS nor STS):

> Thrust Oscillation Mitigation Approach
>
> Aft Skirt Reaction Mass Actuators

> NASA Releases Plan For Ares I Vibration Problem
>
> Since last fall NASA has been faced with the news that vibrations up to 0.5 G inherent in the design of its solid rocket boosters will make the new Ares I a rough ride.

[image]

> To deal with the few seconds of highest vibration the crew will experience at about 115 seconds into the flight, an active “tuned mass absorption” system consisting of 16 100-lb. **weights arranged in a ring around the aft skirt** of the first stage will sense motion and move the masses to **cancel out vibration**, bringing it down to 0.25 G.
>
> All modifications would be limited to the Ares I rocket itself to avoid changes to the Orion capsule design that would mean having to drag the added weight of those systems all the way to the Moon and back. Still, the weight added to Ares I for the active and passive dampening systems will reduce the payload capacity by about 1,200-1,400 lbs.

https://www.wired.com/2008/08/nasa-releases-p/

[image]

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dbda/f0edf98230369767a11ad785043e423d538f.pdf

http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum39/HTML/000175.html

https://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/human-spaceflight/sls-boosters-complete-skirt-off-motor-test/

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20220008197/downloads/SCLV_2022_BPPT_Rev2%20Artemis.pdf

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20205010276/downloads/SLS%20Liftoff%20and%20Separation%20Dynamics%20Analysis%20Tool%20Chain.pdf

Frangible Nut:

[image]

Comment: Great comprehensive answer!

Comment: I'd also point out, though I'm aware you may have mentioned this:
They assist in the dark art of Centre-of-Pressure distribution; they not only support the craft on the pad, but on vehicles such as Ares 1X, create a shift towards the base of the rocket in drag, stabilising passively.

Comment: @RegenerativelyCooledAstronaut citation needed.

Comment: @RegenerativelyCooledAstronaut The Wikipedia page for Ares I-X claims the skirt contained steel ballast to move the CG rearward, which is going to have the opposite effect from moving the CP back with drag. It claims this was done to cause the first stage to tumble more after separation. That section is marked as [citation needed], though, so no idea what the source is.

Comment: FWIW, it was the hold-down _nuts_, not the bolts, that were frangible...

Comment: @RegenerativelyCooledAstronaut after some search i found some reference but not in its entirety. I have added it to he end of the answer.

Comment: Bit of a confusion here, the ballast seems to be regarding vibration reduction, not shifting the base CG ?

Comment: cheers @blobbymcblobby
If there is anything else that I can do to find sources, feel free to ask