# Why was the risk of loss of STS-1 (Columbia) estimated to be so high?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, risk-management, shuttle-columbia

There's [this tweet from Wayne Hale, former NASA Flight Director](https://twitter.com/waynehale/status/1256348518429622272)

> Several media people have asked me about how risky STS-1 was. There were a lot of uninformed guesses circulating in 1981. Thirty years later, based on everything we knew, we back calculated the probability of loss of crew and vehicle to be 1 in 9. That is pretty risky.

Why would the loss factor be estimated to be so high? Is there any methodology or report he was referring to here?

Comment: He might answer if you ask on twitter. I'm guessing they looked at all the stuff that went wrong which they didn't expect (sound pressure at liftoff, bad aero, etc) and figured out the chance of that killing them, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Pretty poor estimating if you ask me; by my hindsight calculation the risk of losing STS-1 was zero. ;)

Comment: Technically, there _were_ fatalities on STS-1 -- the flight went off OK, but during testing ... [that was a different story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-1).

Comment: Related, but *not duplicate:* https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4146/26446